# how to redirect the user to their own page (ROR and Devise Gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes

ok, bear with me here, please.

i'm asking a question in which i'm not fully conversant of all the technical details, etc. (in other words, please take it easy on me for not being fully up on the par).

i've created a ROR application with Devise's gem ... it allows you to sign in, sign up, and log out.

it's very simple, and it just has a page in which you fill in your name, favorite hobby, & book. (hey, it's just an example)

i've also used their redirect code to go this page:

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    posts_path
  end
```

the thing is that ... this page is public to *everyone* who logs in.

how do i redirect the user to *their* own page? and not see everyone's else "notes."

i've looked around ... and Devise has [a link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb) on sessions_controllers ...

do i use that? i don't fully understand the purpose of it.

if yes, how? still trying to figure out how all the puzzle pieces fit together, and it's hard to do that when you don't have full understanding of the topic itself.

or is there another way that's simpler?

if this question is too broad, please let me know ... but i'm not really quite sure how to break it down.

in essence, what i'm really asking is how do i have a user be directed to their own page and not see anyone else's page.

thanks in advance for any help/advice/pointers/etc.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's assume your User model `has_many :posts`. In your PostsController index action (the default [RESTful route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) would be posts_path) you can put something like this:

```
@posts = current_user.posts
```

and when visiting the index view you will only see the current user's posts.

That being said, you are not limited to the index view. You can customize any view you'd like and have a corresponding Controller action with declared instance variables which you can manipulate in your views.

Does that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(user) # note: user or w/e your model is named
  users_path(current_user)
end
```

Comment: um ... ok ... wasn't expecting a response so fast. unfortunately, i can't test it right now. i have to go. will respond as soon i get back. thank you again.

Comment: it will be not users_path, but user_path(current_user). And you have to make sessions_controller. And i'd recommend to add cancan gem so the only owner of page(if i understood correctly your code) could see it

Comment: Edited. I edited the after_sign_in_path this way [in this sample app](https://github.com/nicooga/ogapg/blob/master/app/controllers/application_controller.rb), dont't know if it still works the same way.

Comment: @nicooga ... put that in application controller, and this is what i got: undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<Devise::SessionsController:0x00000100c13300>. the thing is that method that's in my post ... it's from Devise. here's the page ... https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-out

Comment: @sannySin, i'd like to avoid cancan gem b/c it's a bit complicated and i need to finish it today ... hence hoping to do this in a simpler fashion.

Comment: @sannySin, if I need to make sessions_controller, again, not fully sure what they are ... do I use Devise's sessions as posted in the link in my post?